# default date constraint has null records

Tags: sql-server, constraints, default

We are having occasionally EMPTY records in our table/column below when there are multiple records inserted at one shot. While technically this is allowed since the column is nullable, the default constraint should apply for every row inserted.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JOB] ADD [DATE_CREATED] [nvarchar](35) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_JOB_DATE_CREATED]  DEFAULT (sysdatetime())
```

The one possible reason I could think of is  "The default will only apply if you don't insert explicitly to that column". But I couldn't find anywhere code does that but I'm still working on that. Any other possible reasons?

We are on SQL Server 2012. The purpose of the column is to capture created date and time for processing. We can't have this column Non-nullable as this is a reporting column which shouldn't have a business impact.

Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Why not make it NOT NULL? Unless something is specifically inserting a NULL it will use your default and the NOT NULL constraint is a non-issue.

Comment: Yes, it should be not null.  It doesn't matter that it's a metadata column, you expect it to always be populated.  At the very least, turn it on to find the code that's explicitly inserting null.

Comment: You can also update a nullable column with a default to be null after it has been inserted. As an aside, why on earth would have a date created column that is `nvarchar(35)` - your default is a datetime2, that should be your data type - [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: thanks for commenting. @GarathD Due to compatibility - not all client systems support datetime2.

Comment: @Dan Field - I thought the same but want to keep that as a last option as it requires some effort to setup the system similar to prod.

Comment: @user1776609, I tried this on SQL 2012 and it worked. I say, if you are using an application to insert data, run profiler and see what query is executed on server, if not, provide a sample query you are using to insert data.

Answer (score 1):

Make the column NOT NULL.  At the very least, do that so you can capture what application/query is explicitly inserting NULLs - which really just shouldn't be allowed.

Short of that, create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_JOB_CreateDate
ON dbo.JOB
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE j
      SET DateInserted = GETDATE() -- consider using GETUTCDATE()
    FROM JOB j
    INNER JOIN inserted i 
    ON i.PrimaryKeyName = JOB.PrimaryKeyName
END
```

However, this could result in some additional transactional overhead, and won't stop someone from updating the column to `= NULL`.  But again, if having that be null breaks something, then you really should just have the column be `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Well, after insert creates a problem of data accuracy. Hundreds of records added to this table and we are hoping 7 digits accuracy of datetime2 keeps these records unique.

Comment: From what I am getting to based on comments, looks like setting explicit null is what creates the problem. I will head to that direction. Thanks!!

Comment: Ouch. Are you saying you are using the value of a datetime to make a unique row?? Is it also your primary key??

Comment: No. This is not part of primary key. But we expect this is not to be duplicate. (due to crappy old client systems)

Comment: There is no sensible way to guarantee or enforce uniqueness on this column.  If you want uniqueness, add another column that's an identity or defaulted to the `NEXT VALUE FOR` a sequence.